# How to convert text into audio?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When tabIndex on particular button listen audio(i.e. read the instruction text which have given in text .json file). Here not a used preloading .mp3 file. I want to used dynamically convert text to audio conversion. One more thing want to support all devices.

Comment: Not possible when "want to support all devices". For some environments, see [Speech API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API).

Comment: Please be more clear what is going on and what kind of information you wish to achieve, your question lacks information

Answer (score 1):

You should check [this](http://responsivevoice.org/) out . All you have to do is include the library like

```
<script src='https://code.responsivevoice.org/responsivevoice.js'></script>
```

and bind the speak function

```
<input onclick='responsiveVoice.speak("Hello World");' type='button' value='Play' />
```

This library is free for non commercial use. plus it is cross platform